# ReferenceError with AdminGroupsSettings

Tags: google-admin-sdk

I want to create a very simple script

```
function myFunction() {
  var group = AdminGroupsSettings.newGroups();
  Logger.log(group)
}
```

But I have the error `ReferenceError: AdminGroupsSettings is not defined`.
However, my Admin SDK is well added from Services.
The function is a simple copy from the  [Update a group's settings example](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/admin-sdk-groups-settings?authuser=0#update_a_groups_settings)

Comment: This is not reproducible on my side. If I add the Advanced Service, I don't get any error. Make sure the `Identifier` is actually `AdminGroupsSettings`.

Comment: I had added the Admin SDK API instead of the Groups Settings API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Groups Setting API` seems to be different from the `Admin SDK API`.
I recommend using the Admin SDK API instead of the Groups Setting API.